How to move / change / rearrange partition order
Is it possible to rearrange partition order, because i had to recreate my EFI partition and it's on the end of the system partition instead of being at the begining. I am asking if there's some easy solution or maybe some third party tool that would allow for some disk partions rearranging.


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Yes, but not easily. You will need a third party partition editor for it, and you can only resize partitions to create space before the partition before you can move it, so in your case you need at least 100 MB (although 500MB is recommended) of free space on C. A free tool that can do this is AIOMEI Partition Manager Standard. Make sure you do each operation seperately, or it may work a really long time, then fail and put your computer back to what it was before, wasting hours of your time.

It would be easier to move the EFI partition to the end instead of the beginning. I only mention this in case you are trying to add the unallocated space to the Windows 11 partition. If so, then you should add this to your question.
